# App installs in debug build but not in release build?

Tags: android

I am using the [these instructions](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#cert) to build a signed, aligned version of my app.

However, when I install the signed version of my app `adb install bin/Foo-release.apk`, the app does not show up in the apps list on my phone.

On the other hand, when I install the debug version, the app does appear on my phone.

Note that the output of `adb install` is the same in both cases.

Is there something obvious that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that I was not uninstalling the debug version properly before trying to install the release version. I was using the command  `adb shell pm uninstall -k my.package.name`, which makes the Application Icon disappear but apparently does not fully remove it.

Instead I needed to use `adb uninstall my.package.name`.